# Django pagination - how to redirect back to a ListView and a page number

Tags: python, django

In a `ListView` I render a table using the Paginator with `paginate_by = 5`.
In each row I have a Button that opens the `UpdateView`.
After a successful update I'm back on my `ListView` but always on the first page.
How can I change the `success_url` so that I'm back on the page number, from where I opened the `UpdateView`?
Is there a proper way in Django to solve this?

```
#views.py

class Orders_list(ListView):
    model = Order
    context_object_name = "orders"
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    paginate_by = 5
    template_name = "orders/orders_list.html"

#http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders/?page=4


class Orders_update(UpdateView):
    model = Order
    form_class = Order_UpdateForm
    template_name = "orders/orders_update.html"
    #success_url = '../../../orders/'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('orders')


#urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^orders/$', Orders_list.as_view()),
    url(r'^orders/detail/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', Orders_detail.as_view()),
]


#forms.py

class Order_UpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['order_text', 'customer', 'cyclist']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Order_UpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['cyclist'].queryset = Cyclist.objects.filter(active=True)


#models.py

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer')
    cyclist = models.ForeignKey('Cyclist')
    order_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pick_up = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    changed_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def created(self):
        self.changed_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_text


class Customer(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    changed_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def created(self):
        self.changed_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self): return self.company_name


class Cyclist(models.Model):
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    changed_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def created(self):
        self.changed_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lastname
```

**Update**

I found a way to solve this (may be). But I still miss something.

What I did so far:

In the `ListView` template I extended the Url...

```
window.open("{{ request.path }}update/" + id + "/?page=" + {{ page_obj.number }});
```

...then in the view I overwrote the `get_context_data` method...

```
#views.py

class Orders_update(UpdateView):
    model = Order
    form_class = Order_UpdateForm
    template_name = "orders/orders_update.html"
    page = "1" # Assigned

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Orders_update, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        page = self.request.GET.get('page') # Modified
        return context

    success_url = '../../../orders/?page=' + str(page) # Should be used here to redirect to a specific page on a ListView
```

...but now...how can I access the variable `page` in `views.py` in the `success_url`? 
I think this is something very basic (hopefully) and I think I don't understand how scope works in Python.

Comment: I updated my question, have a look in the views.py.

Comment: There is no success_url attribute or get_success_url() method for ListView. So you may override `render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs)` and then provide an HttpResponseRedirect with your url, Also you have provide context data too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what finally worked for me. Basically I just overwrote the `get_success_url` to have access to the `page` parameter from the request.

```
class Orders_update(UpdateView):
    model = Order
    form_class = Order_UpdateForm
    template_name = "orders/orders_update.html"

    def get_success_url(self):
        global page
        page = self.request.GET.get('page')
        return reverse_lazy('orders')
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got finished pulling my hair out with this same problem. Here is what I did. Start in views.py in your ListView, Order_list, and add context data:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['current_page'] = self.request.GET.get('page', 1)
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

The above code passes only the current page number into the ListView template.
Then go to the corresponding list view template and add the following in the object list loop:

```
 {% if is_paginated %}
        <a href="{% url 'order_update' pk=order.pk %}?next={{current_page}}">Update
            </a>
            {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'order_update' pk=order.pk %}">Update
            {% endif %}
```

The if statement allows the page to work without pagination. Note the `?next={{current_page}}` variable. The "current_page" comes from the context_data in the view. This bit passes the current page number to the "next" variable in the url of the page in the anchor tag. This is what my update view url looks like with this variable in it: `http://localhost:8000/food/406/update?next=1`. See the `?next=1` in the url.
Next, go back to views.py to your UpdateView, Order_update, and change the success url with this code:

```
def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        if self.request.GET.get('next'):
            return f"/orders?page={self.request.GET.get('next', 1)}"
        else:
            return '/orders'
```

You'll have to remove the success_url declaration in this view. The `def get_success_url` function wants a string. Reverse seems to work well, but a formatted string will not work in a redirect() statement. It needs to be a plain string. See [TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57269166/typeerror-quote-from-bytes-expected-bytes-after-redirect) for more on that.

If I broke that down too much, I'm sorry. I don't mean to insult your knowledge. I'm still learning and I wrote this the way I would have needed it earlier today before I figured this out.