# TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes after redirect

Tags: python, django

I wrote a function which after execution returns the user to the anchor page. But I'm getting an error.

```
TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
```

**view.py**

```
class CourseEditView(AuthorizedMixin, UpdateView):
    """
    Edit course instances
    """
    model = Courses
    form_class = CoursesEditForm
    template_name = 'additional_info_edit.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        pk = self.object.employee.pk
        return redirect('{}#education'.format(reverse('profile', kwargs={'pk': pk})))
```

How  to avoid a mistake?

**UPD  traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/y700/Env/cv-base-XRtgVf2K/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/y700/Env/cv-base-XRtgVf2K/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/y700/Env/cv-base-XRtgVf2K/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/y700/Env/cv-base-XRtgVf2K/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/y700/Env/cv-base-XRtgVf2K/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/y700/Env/cv-base-XRtgVf2K/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/y700/projects/CV/cv-base/ems/base/views.py", line 35, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/y700/Env/cv-base-XRtgVf2K/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/y700/Env/cv-base-XRtgVf2K/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 194, in post
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/y700/Env/cv-base-XRtgVf2K/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 142, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "/home/y700/Env/cv-base-XRtgVf2K/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 126, in form_valid
    return super().form_valid(form)
  File "/home/y700/Env/cv-base-XRtgVf2K/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 57, in form_valid
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
  File "/home/y700/Env/cv-base-XRtgVf2K/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 456, in __init__
    self['Location'] = iri_to_uri(redirect_to)
  File "/home/y700/Env/cv-base-XRtgVf2K/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 148, in iri_to_uri
    return quote(iri, safe="/#%[]=:;$&()+,!?*@'~")
  File "/home/y700/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/parse.py", line 791, in quote
    return quote_from_bytes(string, safe)
  File "/home/y700/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/parse.py", line 816, in quote_from_bytes
    raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes")
TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
[30/Jul/2019 10:04:33] "POST /course/11/edit/ HTTP/1.1" 500 133528
```

Comment: Please share the traceback

Comment: @IainShelvington I'm sorry for the late answer, I've updated the question

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_success_url), `get_success_url` should just return the URL to redirect to, not the redirect response

```
return '{}#education'.format(reverse('profile', kwargs={'pk': pk}))
```

Comment: Facepalm. Cheers, mate.