# How do I view the profile of the authenticated user in Django Rest Framework using the Token

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, token, django-rest-auth

I am learning DRF and creating a simple DRF app that lets user login, and view the profile and update the profile. I am using Django's default `User` model and using Knox for Token Authentication (if it can be done easier using Django Rest Authentication, please let me know and also tell me the procedure).

I have successfully created the API to register and login the user which works fine, but I am stuck at showing the profile to the Authenticated User through a Token.

I am only one Model that is `Details` which acts as to store the Profile details of the user. I have `LoginSerializer` which is connected to Login API and `MainUserSerializer` & `UserSerializer`, both of which are connected to User API (which acts to show the Profile details on frontend).

I have tried a lot, searched everywhere, but all they show is how to authenticate the user with token through a url (some thing like using `curl https://localhost:8000/api/user...` etc.), postman, somehing like `http post -a...` command in terminal and other ways, but I don't want to test or implement using these ways. I want something that if I open my user profile url after logging in the user using the link `localhost:8000/user`, then at the backend it should do like following as mentioned here [enter link description here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/22/how-to-implement-token-authentication-using-django-rest-framework.html):

```
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Token 9054f7aa9305e012b3c2300408c3dfdf390fcddf'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

I have tried really hard, but I am unable to successfully go to the details page by authenticating user via token.

My **`models.py`** is:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Detail(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(verbose_name="CSV File", upload_to='csv_files')
    file_desc = models.TextField("CSV File Description")

    def __str__(self):
        return ("{} ({} {})".format(self.user.email, self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return (self.file_desc)
```

My **`serializers.py`** is:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Detail
from rest_framework import serializers


class MainUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    usr = MainUserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Detail
        fields = ['usr', 'file', 'file_desc']

class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        user = authenticate(**{'username': data['email'], 'password': data['password']})
        if user and user.is_active:
            return user
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Incorrect Credentials Passed.')
```

My **`views.py`** is:

```
import requests
from rest_framework import permissions
from knox.models import AuthToken
from .serializers import UserSerializer, LoginSerializer
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from rest_framework.renderers import TemplateHTMLRenderer
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class LoginAPIHTML(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'accounts/login.html'

    def get(self, request):        
        serializer = LoginSerializer()
        return Response({'serializer': serializer})

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response({'serializer': serializer})
        
        user = serializer.validated_data
        url = 'http://' + str(request.get_host()) + str(reverse('user', args=None))

        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Token ' + str(AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1])
        }

        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, format='json')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(r)
```

My **`urls.py`** is:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import LoginAPIHTML

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/', include('knox.urls')),
    path('login', LoginAPIHTML.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('user', UserAPI.as_view(), name='user'),
]
```

and below is my **`settings.py`**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'accounts',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'knox',
    ...
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}

REST_AUTH_TOKEN_MODEL = 'knox.models.AuthToken'
REST_AUTH_TOKEN_CREATOR = 'project.apps.accounts.utils.create_knox_token'
```

Whenever, I put the correct credentials in the Login API at `localhost:8000/login`, then instead of redirecting to the details page at `localhost:8000/user`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError at /login
quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login
Django Version: 4.0.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
quote_from_bytes() expected bytes

Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 55, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
Local vars
C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 197, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
Local vars
C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py, line 54, in wrapped_view
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs) …
Local vars
C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py, line 84, in view
            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) …
Local vars
C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py, line 509, in dispatch
            response = self.handle_exception(exc) …
Local vars
C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py, line 469, in handle_exception
            self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc) …
Local vars
C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py, line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
        raise exc …
Local vars
C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py, line 506, in dispatch
            response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs) …
Local vars
C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\Downloads\Meistery\Round2\backend_dev_trial_ass_r2\accounts\views.py, line 202, in post
        return HttpResponseRedirect(r) …
Local vars
C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\http\response.py, line 538, in __init__
        self["Location"] = iri_to_uri(redirect_to) …
Local vars
C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py, line 139, in iri_to_uri
    return quote(iri, safe="/#%[]=:;$&()+,!?*@'~") …
Local vars
C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\parse.py, line 870, in quote
    return quote_from_bytes(string, safe) …
Local vars
C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\parse.py, line 895, in quote_from_bytes
        raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes") …
Local vars
```

I am fed up of this. It would be better if it sets up either using Knox or using Django Rest Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

This should be of help:

https://studygyaan.com/django/django-rest-framework-tutorial-register-login-logout

I use this has a guide anytime am using Knox with drf.

Looking at the error logs you posted:

`Local vars C:\Users\Khubaib Khawar\Downloads\Meistery\Round2\backend_dev_trial_ass_r2\accounts\views.py, line 202, in post return HttpResponseRedirect(r) …`

`HttpResponseRedirect` expects the url or endpoint to be redirected to.
But the variable r is returning a response from the `GET` request made at:

`r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, format='json')`

hence the error:
 `raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes") …`

I think this is similar to :

[TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57269166/typeerror-quote-from-bytes-expected-bytes-after-redirect)

Based on your second comment:

- you could try based off your code:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

....

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, format='json')
return Response(r.json(), status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

or

- You could try separating your login view from your profile view. There is something called `single responsibility` in
  SOLID principle. your login view should authenticate the user and return a valid token. And your profile view should be a protected view
  that requires the user to be authenticated and has the right permission to view his user profile.

your profile view would look like this:

```
from rest_framework import mixins, authentication, permissions, status, viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response

from core import models
from users.serializers import UserProfileSerializer

class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet,
                         mixins.ListModelMixin,
                         mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                         mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                         ):
    """User profile endpoint"""
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    queryset = models.UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.UserProfile.objects.filter(
            user=self.request.user.id)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):

        return serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        user_obj = models.UserProfile.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk'])
        user = request.user

        if user_obj.user.id == user.id:

            serializer = UserProfileSerializer(
                user_obj,
                data=request.data)

            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data)
            return Response(
                serializer.errors,
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return Response(
                'Unauthorized',
                status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

I hope this helps

Comment: The URL you provided does not answer my question..

Comment: how do I solve that error? Or is there any other approach to achieve what I am trying to?

Comment: I tried the way you mentioned that is `r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, format='json')`, but it gave me this error `TypeError: Session.request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'format'`.

Comment: and the second option that you gave does not apply in my case. Actually I want that when a user logs in, so after logging in the app should redirect user directly to the Profile Page or you can say a Dashboard page.